# parse.com Rest API $regex not returning results

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to get substring of a field `businessTitle`. `businessTitle` field have the value "Andy James Magician" while i am searching for "Andy" using `$regex`. I am using following piece of code:

```
$postData = array();
$postData['where'] = '{"businessTitle":{"$regex":"\QAndy\E"}}'; 
$query = http_build_query($postData, '', '&');
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/users?'.$query;

//start curl operation
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
$users_array = json_decode($data);
```

When print `print_r($users_array);` it returns 0 results. Here is the response that i get from parse.com Rest API

```
stdClass Object ( [results] => Array ( ) [count] => 0 )
```

How i can get my desired results.

Thanks

Comment: I can't find any reference to $regex as a possible option to the where parameter. Where did you find it?

Comment: I also want to do something similar, like described here https://www.parse.com/questions/rest-api-regex-case-insensitive What's wrong with the $regex?